# Computing Variable using SYSMIS

Tags: spss

I'm running into a problem that I've never encountered before and I cannot quite figure out what's going on.

I am trying to compute a variable as follows:

```
COMPUTE A=$SYSMIS.
IF B=$SYSMIS A=$SYSMIS.
IF C > SUM(B, 1) A= 1.
IF C = SUM(B, 1) A= 2.
IF C = B A= 2.
IF C < B A=3.
```

This runs fine except for the fact that when B=$SYSMIS there are very clear examples of A that are not in fact missing.

I tested it using:

```
TEMP.
SELECT IF B=$SYSMIS.
FREQ A.
```

It tells me that "No cases were input to this procedure. Either there are none in the working data file or all of them have been filtered out."

Meaning, the code worked correctly.

But...I found over 1,000 cases that are not fitting this logic.

```
TEMP.
SELECT IF ID=102.
FREQ A B.
```

This shows a specific ID that has A=$SYSMIS and B=2.

[image]

A, B and C are all numeric.

Thanks in advance for any insight! (:

Comment: instead of `IF B=$SYSMIS` try `if missing(B)` - for computing, for analysis and for `select`

Comment: This still comes up with the same result. I just added *IF Missing(B) A=$SYSMIS* to the original logic. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: The missing(B) is definitely the problem. When I check it using the `TEMP. Select if Missing(B)`, I can see all the answers in A that I want to delete...but I cant get it to work within the logic to delete the answers in A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, instead of `IF B=$SYSMIS` you should use `if missing(B)` - for computing, for analysis and for select.
Another probable reason for your results is in commands like this:

```
IF C > SUM(B, 1) A=1.
```

If B is missing, the result of `SUM(B, 1)` is 1. Therefore if `C>1` A gets the value 1, in spite of B being missing.
There are two ways to overcome this.
First, using `X+Y` instead of `sum(X,Y)` will result in a missing value when X or Y is missing:

```
IF C > (B + 1) A=1.
```

Second option: put the command `COMPUTE A=$SYSMIS.` at the end of the syntax instead of the beginning, so any values entered in A when B is missing will be replaced with a missing value.

Comment: Ah, I didnt even think about the SUM vs + situation. That makes perfect sense. Thank you so much!